# Разбиение массива на блоки

Tags: c, массивы, jpeg, blocks

**Необходимо разбить массив на блоки 8x8 и блоки записать в отдельный массив.**
Для начала хотел бы понять, как это реализовывается на простом примере предоставленном ниже (Массив 36 элементов, разбить на блоки 2х2, блоки записать в отдельный массив).

```
const int row = 6;
const int col = 6;
const int temprow = 2;
const int tempcol = 2;
int *temp = (int *) malloc(temprow * tempcol * sizeof(int));
int *array = (int *) malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
int *arrayBlocks = (int *) malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        *(array + i * col + j) = rand() % 100;
        cout << *(array + i * col + j) << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Не стоит смешивать С и С++. cout -- вывод в стиле С++, а в С его нет. malloc -- выделение памяти в стиле С.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса совершенно непонятно какие условия задачи. Напишите примеры, как по-Вашему должен преобразовываться массив 10x10 в 8x8 и как, например, 20x100 (если ассиметрия допустима).

Comment: @0andriy Количество строк и столбцов кратно 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы рассматриваете двумерные массивы (размера `(n, m)`), однако в коде у вас одномерные массивы. (размера `n * m`). Я бы настоятельно рекомендовал так не делать: это ухудшает читаемость кода. Возможно вы так сделали из соображений производительности. Так как в вопросе используются такие массивы, то и ответе также будут использоваться они.

Рассмотрим исходный массив. Это таблица размера шесть на шесть. В каждой ячейке записана пара чисел: вертикальный и горизонтальный индексы.

```
0,0  0,1  0,2  0,3  0,4  0,5

1,0  1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5

2,0  2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  2,5

3,0  3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4  3,5

4,0  4,1  4,2  4,3  4,4  4,5

5,0  5,1  5,2  5,3  5,4  5,5
```

Мы хотим разбить этот массив на блоки размера два на два. Введём понятия вертикальный и горизонтальный индексы блока. Они будут принимать значения из множества `{0, 1, 2}`. Тогда каждой ячейке исходного массива можно сопоставить вертикальный и горизонтальный индексы блока, ей соответствующего:

```
0,0  0,0  0,1  0,1  0,2  0,2

0,0  0,0  0,1  0,1  0,2  0,2

1,0  1,0  1,1  1,1  1,2  1,2

1,0  1,0  1,1  1,1  1,2  1,2

2,0  2,0  2,1  2,1  2,2  2,2

2,0  2,0  2,1  2,1  2,2  2,2
```

Насколько я понял, в результате вы хотите получить массив блоков. Блок --- это двумерный массив размера `(2, 2)`. Поэтому вы хотите получить трёхмерный массив размера `(число_блоков, 2, 2)`. В нашем случае `число_блоков` равно девяти. Алгоритм может быть, например, таким:

- рассматриваем каждую ячейку исходного массива.
- определяем вертикальный и горизонтальный индексы блока, к которому относится текущая ячейка.
- определяем индекс блока по формуле:

  ```
  индекс_блока = вертикальный_индекс_блока * число_блоков_по_горизонтали + горизонтальный_индекс_блока
  ```
- Пусть `blocks` --- наш трёхмерный массив блоков. Тогда ячейке `(iBlock, jBlock)` блока с номером `k` будет соответствовать ячейка `block[(k * число_элементов_в_блоке) + (iBlock * ширина_блока + jBlock)]`. В нашем случае `ширина_блока` равна двум, `число_элементов_в_блоке` равно четырём.

Возможная реализация:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//  исходный массив --- размера (n, m)
//  блоки --- размера (nBlock, mBlock)
    const int n = 6;
    const int m = 6;
    const int nBlock = 2;
    const int mBlock = 2;
//  двумерный массив размера (n, m)
//  элемент [i][j] лежит в ячейке с номером i * n + j
    int *array = (int *) malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
//  элемент [k][i][j] лежит в ячейке с номером (k * число_элементов_в_блоке) + (i * nBlock + j)
//  трёхмерный массив размера (число_блоков, nBlock, mBlock)
    int *blocks = (int *) malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            array[i * m + j] = rand() % 10;
            printf("%d ", array[i * m + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

//  разбиение
    int numberBlocksVertical = n / nBlock;
    int numberBlocksHorizontal = m / mBlock;
    int numberElementsInBlock = nBlock * mBlock;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            int verticalBlockIndex = i / nBlock;
            int horizontalBlockIndex = j / mBlock;
            int iBlock = i % nBlock;
            int jBlock = j % mBlock;
            int indexOfBlock = verticalBlockIndex * numberBlocksHorizontal + horizontalBlockIndex;
            blocks[(indexOfBlock * numberElementsInBlock) + (iBlock * mBlock + jBlock)] = array[i * n + j];
        }
    }

//  вывод на экран для проверки
    int numberBlocks = numberBlocksHorizontal * numberBlocksVertical;
    for (int indexOfBlock = 0; indexOfBlock < numberBlocks; ++indexOfBlock) {
        printf("Блок #%d:\n", indexOfBlock);
        for (int iBlock = 0; iBlock < nBlock; iBlock++) {
            for (int jBlock = 0; jBlock < mBlock; jBlock++) {
                printf("%d ", blocks[(indexOfBlock * numberElementsInBlock) + (iBlock * mBlock + jBlock)]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
3 6 7 5 3 5 
6 2 9 1 2 7 
0 9 3 6 0 6 
2 6 1 8 7 9 
2 0 2 3 7 5 
9 2 2 8 9 7 

Блок #0:
3 6 
6 2 
Блок #1:
7 5 
9 1 
Блок #2:
3 5 
2 7 
Блок #3:
0 9 
2 6 
Блок #4:
3 6 
1 8 
Блок #5:
0 6 
7 9 
Блок #6:
2 0 
9 2 
Блок #7:
2 3 
2 8 
Блок #8:
7 5 
9 7
```